# Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.even with static configuration from heroku docs

Tags: python, django, heroku

After trying to upload my django-project to heroku i get the following error, even though I tried to configure setting.py in accordance with heroku documentation. Tried to fix it myself for couple of days but I clearly got no idea about what is wrong.

```
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput 
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
           main()
         File "manage.py", line 17, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
           self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
           output = self.handle(*args, **options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
           collected = self.collect()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 104, in collect
           for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 130, in list
           for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
           directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 316, in listdir
           for entry in os.scandir(path):
       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_3daca1eccd4631486a8597ada28d44da/static'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is my django settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '6e71nuw7=a-eow4ywhqfp6f+_7s-y7wo!4scy7xhj2vbem3@)m'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["dyadyanurik-visitka.herokuapp.com/", "127.0.0.1"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'visitka.apps.VisitkaConfig',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Any ideas about it?

Comment: do you have a static folder in the base directory of your project?

Comment: Only in app. Is it mandatory to have it in main one as well?

Comment: This error message `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_3daca1eccd4631486a8597ada28d44da/static'` means you need to add `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` in `settings.py`. **Also it won't work unless you add files into static folder**